# Is it possible to get numeric index (position) of marks in tkinter text?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to find the position of certain mark within tkinter text. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Text.index`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.index-method) method to get the "line.column" index corresponding to the given index.

```
pos = text.index(INSERT)
```

Comment: @SureshSubedi: `index` works with marks. This is the correct answer.

Comment: Indeed! It does work with mark. I was asking for position before setting mark in my code.